# How to get field in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have the following query:

```
product = session.query(ProductTable).filter(ProductTable.image_d == 0).first()
```

When I try to get the value of the field:

```
print (product["sku"])
```

I get an error:

```
'ProductTable' object is not subscribable
```

Comment: Try `product.sku`

Comment: It works, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the ways by which you can get the fields from sqlalchemy

**FIRST METHOD**

```
product = session.query(ProductTable).filter(ProductTable.image_d == 0).first()
sku = product.sku
```

**SECOND METHOD** - select only required fields in that case query needs to change like below

```
sku,image_d = session.query(ProductTable.sku,ProductTable.image_d ).filter(ProductTable.image_d == 0).first()
```

In second method sqlalchemy returns you the tuple accordigly you can unpack for required values